# Find matchesm between parts of strings in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with urls, like

```
    A   B
1   example.com/id/1/baz/   site.com/id/2/ban/
2   example.com/id/3/boom/  site.com/id/3/baff/
3   example.com/id/123/foo/ site.com/id/321/bar/
```

What i need is to compare IDs in corresponding cells of the same row (A1 vs. B1, A2 vs. B2) and write into C false if IDs are different and true, if they are same.

The formula i currently use is

`=LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A2,FIND("/id/",A1)+4,99),"/",REPT(" ",99)),99)=LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(B1,FIND("/id/",B1)+4,99),"/",REPT(" ",99)),99)`

But the formula works if urls are EXACTLY so, as in the cited table. If any url has nothing after ID, like `example.com/id/1` the formula produces false negatives.

How could the formula be adjusted to proceed urls without an after-id-slug?

Comment: let me know if you want to see an approach using `powerquery` which can solve the issue with a few clicks using built-in functions.

Comment: @TerryW - sure! With pleasure!

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),2*LEN(A1)+1,LEN(A1)))=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(B1,"/",REPT(" ",LEN(B1))),2*LEN(B1)+1,LEN(B1)))
```

This would simply break up the string into seperate words with the "/" as a delimiter. That way you are comparing the nth word of the first string with the nth worth of another. In this case the 3rd "word", being the id, of A1 and B1.

Change `..2*..` into `..3*..` to compare the 4th word etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can search the substring in the other:

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(LEFT(MID(A1,FIND("/id/",A1),LEN(A1))&"/",FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND("/id/",A1),LEN(A1))&"/","/","}}}",3))),B1&"/"))
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: I'm afraid this wouldn't work on a string when there is nothing afther the actual ID number as per OP's note, e.g.: `example.com/id/1`. Someone else is downvoting the answers btw.

Comment: @JvdV Using an iferror to remove the substitute should be sufficient, though.  I was working on that myself and came up with a very similar approach (used `Replace` rather than substitute/left).  My formula was: `=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(IFERROR(REPLACE(REPLACE(A1,1,FIND("/id/",A1)+3,""),1+FIND("/",REPLACE(A1,1,FIND("/id/",A1)+3,"")),99,""),REPLACE(A1,1,FIND("/id/",A1)+3,"")),B1))`.  Didn't post as an answer due to how close that is to Scott's, and that your approach will also state "FALSE" where "1" is TRUE when found in "123".

Comment: @JvdV see edit, now it does not matter if either is missing the ending `/`

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel 2013+, with the `FILTERXML` function, you can create an XML out of your string using the `/` as the node markers, and then examine the node that follow `id`.

Won't matter if there is nothing following:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>" &SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//t[contains(.,'id')]/s/following-sibling::s[2]")=
FILTERXML("<t><s>" &SUBSTITUTE(B1,"/","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//t[contains(.,'id')]/s/following-sibling::s[2]")
```

[image]

Comment: each time a question like this I can always see you using **FILTERXML** to answer it. It is not so easy to understand the formula but I am quite amazed that it worked every time!! Just wondering if there is an article that I can read to learn more about the logic behind this function? Many thanks :)

Comment: @TerryW I'm just using it as a method to parse delimiter separated substrings from a string. And I'm in the learning phase.  If you search for `xPath` you can learn about the logic behind.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula, similar to the one posted by @JvdV

```
=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,4+FIND("/id/",A1),LEN(A1)),"/",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)))
=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(B1,4+FIND("/id/",B1),LEN(B1)),"/",REPT(" ",LEN(B1))),LEN(B1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see below approach using Power Query which is available in **Excel 2010 and later versions**. Mine is using **Excel 2016**.

[image: PQ]

Here are the codes behind the scene for reference only. All steps are using built-in functions without advanced coding.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table4"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}}),
    #"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Changed Type", "Column1", "Column1 - Copy"),
    #"Duplicated Column1" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Duplicated Column", "Column2", "Column2 - Copy"),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Duplicated Column1", "Column1 - Copy", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({"/id/"}, QuoteStyle.Csv, false), {"Column1 - Copy.1", "Column1 - Copy.2"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Column1 - Copy.1", type text}, {"Column1 - Copy.2", type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type1", "Column1 - Copy.2", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({"/"}, QuoteStyle.Csv, false), {"Column1 - Copy.2.1", "Column1 - Copy.2.2"}),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter1",{{"Column1 - Copy.2.1", Int64.Type}, {"Column1 - Copy.2.2", type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter2" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type2", "Column2 - Copy", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({"/id/"}, QuoteStyle.Csv, false), {"Column2 - Copy.1", "Column2 - Copy.2"}),
    #"Changed Type3" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter2",{{"Column2 - Copy.1", type text}, {"Column2 - Copy.2", type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter3" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type3", "Column2 - Copy.2", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({"/"}, QuoteStyle.Csv, false), {"Column2 - Copy.2.1", "Column2 - Copy.2.2"}),
    #"Changed Type4" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter3",{{"Column2 - Copy.2.1", Int64.Type}, {"Column2 - Copy.2.2", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type4", "Custom", each [#"Column1 - Copy.2.1"]=[#"Column2 - Copy.2.1"]),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Column1", "Column2", "Custom"})
in
    #"Removed Other Columns"
```